# Sony runs which operating system? Oracle Linux or Crestron Extron or Minix or OS X?

Tags: linux, hardware, embedded

Sony has TV, PlayStation, Camera random hardware's. Where many of those have GUI available too.

I want to run my BASH script there with ncurses.

But how do they drive there devices? Which operating system is used inside? 
Or they just use micro-controllers or is it open-solaris?

- Xperia by Sony Ericsson

http://developer.sonymobile.com/wportal/devworld/search-downloads/opensource?cc=gb&lc=en

Comment: is this question regarding Xperia mobile phones? if so then I think they run Android which is based on Linux

Comment: No its not about Xperia, its about Sony which derived Operating system is using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those customer devices run custom operating systems, or a highly-customized embedded Linux or other UNIX-type OS; sometimes not even Bash and ncurses are included.

It's unlikely that you will be able to run your custom scripts (specially after the PlayStation 3/Linux situation), unless you can get more documentation about them - which might be quite difficult unless you go the reverse-engineering path.

Comment: Well if you use custom operating system, is it derived from GPL license then it has to be open source anyway or redirected to open-source. If its closed source like Microsoft then it also need a history like derived from Minix or OS X derived from BSD. Or if its Unix then derived from Bell labs. But Sony is what in such case?

Comment: If you use custom operating system that you wrote (i.e. not Linux, not Windows, not any commercial OS), it's under any license you want. I don't know what Sony uses in this case, however, and this is quite difficult to discover without reverse engineering.

Answer (score 1):

These are mostly completely unrelated devices and all have their own system software.

It's almost guaranteed not to have anything to do with Oracle, Apple, Minix or some other fat brand. It's also unlikely to be Linux or other GPL unless they've hidden that well enough to not be suspected of license violation. Sony has always been very hostile about anyone doing something useful with their systems (except for a moment of [baiting people with Linux on ps3 before withdrawing](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2010/04/29/playstation_3_neutering_lawsuit/)).

[PS3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayStation_3_system_software) also at least has a [hypervisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor). It's hard to say how much of an os [XMB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xmb) is.

Comment: Samsung, runs Linux FYI.

Comment: Linux has rt kernel or -generic kernel mode. Which allows to the same DSP or micro controllers speed/performance if you compare with real-world devices which has different shapes and faces. (just if you remove the disks to avoid disk crashes)

Comment: Samsung is a company, not a device. I really can't parse the second comment or see how it's related to the answer.